# how can I align limits at "lim"?

Tags: align, math-operators

I am trying to align several limit expressions at varying x-values.  It seems that align treats the "limit" portion together with its subscript as an entire object, then aligns these limits, which produces expressions aligned at "x" rather than "lim":

```
\documentclass[reqno,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\addtolength{\jot}{3em}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
    &\lim_{x \to -2} x =&\\
    &\lim_{x \to -1} x =&\\
    &\lim_{\phantom{-}x \to 0} x =&\\
    &\lim_{\phantom{-}x \to 1} x =&\\
    &\lim_{\phantom{-}x \to 2} x =&\\
    &\lim_{\phantom{-}x \to \infty} x =&\\
    &\lim_{x \to -\infty} x =&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

I've tried to place the align marker in other places, and also fudge it using phantoms, (which isn't nice but much better than without).  Is there a way around this so that each expression aligns at "l" in "lim"?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Many thanks for posting a full MWE.

Rather than redefine `\lim` directly to handle your special alignment objective, it is preferable to define a new command called, say, `\mylim`. Modifying directly the ways that LaTeX use to place the argument of a "math operator" such as `\lim` may end up breaking all kinds of things...

The `\mylim` macro defined below takes two arguments: the item that the limit is taken over, and the subscript argument of `\lim`. Note that the arguments are encased in curly braces -- no subscript symbol is used. In the example code below, the outer `array` environment and the vertical bar are used merely to illustrate that "lim" and the subscript argument are both aligned flush-left.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcommand\mylim[2]{%
    \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
     \lim #1 \\[-1ex] \scriptstyle #2 
    \end{array}
}
\begin{document}
\[ \begin{array}{|@{}l}
     \mylim{x}{x \to -2}  =\\
     \mylim{x}{x \to -1}  =\\
     \mylim{x}{x \to 0}  =\\
     \mylim{x}{x \to 1}  =\\
     \mylim{x}{x \to 2}  =\\
     \mylim{y}{y \to \infty}  =\\
     \mylim{k}{k \to -\infty}  =
   \end{array} 
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question: If the objective is to make LaTeX ignore -- for the purpose of horizontal alignment, that is -- whatever may be in the subscript below "lim", while still centering that material below "lim", you could make use of the comment provided by @daleif and employ the `\smashoperator` macro of the [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools) package:

```
\smashoperator{\lim_{x\to-2}} f(x)
```

If you have a lot of these expressions and wish to economize on typing (and reduce the number of typos...), you could define a shortcut macro, e.g.,

```
\newcommand\nlim[1]{\smashoperator{\lim_{#1}}}
```

and then type `\nlim{x\to-2} f(x)`. Note that if the material in the subscript is sufficiently wide, it will "protrude" into the space to the left *and* to right of "lim". I think two-sided protrusion is what you're after. However, if you want the subscript material to protrude only on the left but not on the right, use the option `[l]`, i.e., write

```
\smashoperator[l]{\lim{k\to-\infty}} k
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \smashoperator macro
\newcommand\nlim[1]{\smashoperator{\lim_{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\[ \begin{array}{|@{}l}
     \nlim{x \to -2} x =\\
     \nlim{x \to -1} x =\\
     \nlim{x \to 0} x =\\
     \nlim{x \to 1} x =\\
     \nlim{x \to 2} x =\\
     \nlim{y \to \infty} y =\\
     \nlim{k \to -\infty} k =
   \end{array} 
\]
\end{document}
```

A comment on the *aesthetics* produced by `\mylim` and `\nlim`: If you're going to make the effort to align various rows on the string "lim", you shouldn't risk marring the overall look by letting lim's subscript material protrude to the left of the string. In my opinion, then, you should go with `\mylim` rather than with `\nlim` to achieve your alignment objective.

Comment: Or use `\smashoperator` from `mathtools`, though not 100% what the OP asks for

Comment: This is wonderful.  Thank you!  So my next question would be whether it is possible to center the subscripts, as latex does, yet still align the "lim"?

Comment: @AbbasJaffary - I've written an addendum to address your follow-up comment.

Comment: Thank you again.  Along with Steven's solution proposed below, I would agree that the subscripts aligned at the left look best.  But, it is very nice to have these various options!

Comment: @Mico I get a situation with `$\mylim{\dfrac{x+3}{x^2 - x - m}}{x \to \pm\infty}$` Can you help me?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 - I think it's a poor idea to combine `\mylim` with `\frac`, let alone `\dfrac`. If you insist on using `\mylim` with fractional expressions, all I can suggest is that you use *inline-fraction* notation. E.g., `\mylim{(x+3)/(x^2 - x - m)}{x \to \pm\infty}`, or maybe `\mylim{\bigl((x+3)/(x^2 - x - m)\bigr)}{x \to \pm\infty}`.

Answer (score 5):

This approach, using stacks, permits an optional argument that specifies the gap (default 3pt) between the "lim" line and the subscript, as demonstrated on the lim y line.

In this case `\mylim` (column 1) aligns the argument to the left, while `\myclim` (column 2) aligns the subscript to the center, while keeping the overall alignment with the word "lim".  Finally `\myclimB` (column 3) accounts for the subscript width when placing the argument to the limit.

REVISED SOLUTION to align not only "lim"s but also equals and what follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\mylim[3][3pt]{%
 \def\stackalignment{l}\ensurestackMath{\stackunder[#1]{\lim #2}{\scriptstyle #3}}%
}
\newcommand\myclim[3][3pt]{%
 \def\stackalignment{c}\ensurestackMath{\stackunder[#1]{\lim #2}{%
  \makebox[0pt]{$\scriptstyle #3$}}}%
}
\newcommand\myclimB[3][3pt]{%
 \setbox0=\hbox{$\lim$}%
 \setbox1=\hbox{$\scriptstyle #3$}%
 \ifdim\wd1>\wd0\kern.5\wd0\kern-.5\wd1\fi%
 \def\stackalignment{c}\mathop{\ensurestackMath{\stackunder[#1]{\lim}{%
  \scriptstyle #3}}}#2%
}
\begin{document}
\[
  \setstackgap{L}{2\baselineskip}\def\stackalignment{l}\TABbinary
     \tabbedCenterstack{
     \mylim{x}{x \to -2}  &=&0\\
     \mylim{x}{x \to -1}  &=&0\\
     \mylim{x}{x \to 0}  &=&0\\
     \mylim{x}{x \to 1}  &=&0\\
     \mylim{x}{x \to 2}  &=&0\\
     \mylim[4pt]{y}{y \to \infty}  &=&0\\
     \mylim{k}{k \to -\infty}  &=&0
}
\quad...\quad
\tabbedCenterstack{
     \myclim{x}{x \to -2}  &=&0\\
     \myclim{x}{x \to -1}  &=&0\\
     \myclim{x}{x \to 0}  &=&0\\
     \myclim{x}{x \to 1}  &=&0\\
     \myclim{x}{x \to 2}  &=&0\\
     \myclim[4pt]{y}{y \to \infty}  &=&0\\
     \myclim{k}{k \to -\infty}  &=&0
}
\quad...\quad
\tabbedCenterstack{
     \myclimB{x}{x \to -2}  &=&0\\
     \myclimB{x}{x \to -1}  &=&0\\
     \myclimB{x}{x \to 0}  &=&0\\
     \myclimB{x}{x \to 1}  &=&0\\
     \myclimB{x}{x \to 2}  &=&0\\
     \myclimB[4pt]{y}{y \to \infty}  &=&0\\
     \myclimB{k}{k \to -\infty}  &=&0
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would say that the optimal solution would keep the same spacing and relative placements as `\lim_{k\to-\infty}k` while aligning at the `\lim`.  Would that be achievable using your approach?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch  I am not sure I understand exactly what you are asking.  Adding words like "horizontal" and "vertical" to your question might help, as well as describing "alignment" relative to what.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch  Does my revised solution (aligning the equal signs and what follows, too) have anything to do with your question?

Comment: @Mico No slight taken.  I bow to your superior intellect.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - I'm blushing furiously! :-)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I was completely unclear.  By default, `\lim_{k\to-\infty} k` displays with `k\to-\infty` centered horizontally under the `\lim`, and the trailing `k` separated horizontally from the `\lim` by a space which depends on the subscript of `\lim`.  Would it be possible to have, say, `\lim_{k\to0}k` on one line and `\lim_{k\to-\infty}k` on another line, aligned at the `\lim`, but keeping for each line the default relative positioning (vertical and horizontal) of `\lim`, its subscript, and `k`?  Maybe that should be a Question.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch  Does not the second column of my revised answer accomplish that (at least horizontally)?  By using a `\makebox[0pt]{}`, the actual width of the subscript is masked, and thus will not affect the horizontal spacing between "lim" and "k".

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes No, I mean that the spacing between `\lim` and `k` should be taking into account the subscript (just like the default rendering of `\lim_{k\to-\infty}k`), but that the alignment of several `\lim` should not take into account the subscript.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch As in column 3 of my new revision?

Comment: No: I would like each line to remain identical to how it is in your current column 3, but shifted horizontally in such a way that the `lim` are aligned vertically.  I've asked that as a question if you're interested. [Vertically align at operator, but keep default horizontal spacing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198593/2707)

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch  I believe my latest revision answers your request.  It required a `\kern` if the subscript width exceeded the width of `\lim`.