# Vertically align at operator, but keep default horizontal spacing

Tags: horizontal-alignment, math-operators, subscripts

This is a follow up to «[How can I align limits at “lim”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198290/2707)».  What is the best approach to achieve the following alignment?  Namely, I would like the two `\prod` to be aligned, but each line should remain identical to what (La)TeX produces by default, simply shifted horizontally to match the alignment requirement.

[image: Image of vertically aligned \prod operators]

Here is the code which generates the above.  As you can see, I've used an ad-hoc amount of `\mspace`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.75\textwidth}
  \begin{align*}
    & \prod_{-n\leq k\leq n-1} \left[\frac{k+1}{k}\right] = -1 \\
    & \mspace{16mu} \prod_{1\leq j\leq n} j = \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{m^{n+1} m!}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots(n+m+1)}
  \end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interesting thing is that \tempa gets set to zero at some point and has to be recomputed.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newlength{\tempa}

\newcommand{\aligncenter}[1]% #1=display math to be aligned
{\settowidth{\tempa}{$\displaystyle #1$}%
\hspace{0.5\tempa}&%
\settowidth{\tempa}{$\displaystyle #1$}%
\hspace{-0.5\tempa}#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.75\textwidth}
  \begin{align*}
    \aligncenter{\prod_{-n\leq k\leq n-1}} \left[\frac{k+1}{k}\right] = -1 \\
    \aligncenter{\prod_{1\leq j\leq n}} j = \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{m^{n+1} m!}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots(n+m+1)}
  \end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: equation]

Comment: To avoid recomputing the width you can do `\global\tempa=\tempa` after computing it the first time.  The problem arises because `\settowidth` assigns the value to `\tempa` locally, and `&` ends a group, hence the scope in which `\tempa` was set.

Comment: I have to say I like this approach, as it is not intrusive and as far as I can tell uses the default spacing.

Comment: @Bruno Le Floch - Yeah, I figured as much.  I was thinking at first that \settowidth was global, like \addtolength.  OTOH, a local \tempa is better since one can reuse it.

Answer (score 5):

In this specific case one sub-optimal option would be to use `\smashoperator[l]`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% Loads amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  & \smashoperator[l]{\prod_{-n \leq k \leq n-1}}\left[\frac{k+1}{k}\right] = -1 \\
  & \smashoperator[l]{\prod_{1 \leq j \leq n}} j = \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{m^{n+1} m!}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots(n+m+1)}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I mention sub-optimal as the alignment is achieved, yet the total horizontal width of the `align`ed equation is short about the width of `-n\leq` that has zero width in the top `\prod`. One might correct this with some work. Here's one such attempt:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% Loads amsmath
\DeclareMathOperator*{\dummyop}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  & \smashoperator[l]{\prod_{-n \leq k \leq n-1}}\left[\frac{k+1}{k}\right] = -1 \\
  & \smashoperator[l]{\prod_{1 \leq j \leq n}} j = \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{m^{n+1} m!}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots(n+m+1)}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  & \smashoperator[l]{\prod_{-n \leq k \leq n-1}}\left[\frac{k+1}{k}\right] = -1 \\
  & \smashoperator[l]{\prod_{1 \leq j \leq n}} j = \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{m^{n+1} m!}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots(n+m+1)}
    \hphantom{\smashoperator[r]{\dummyop_{-n \leq k \leq n-1}}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

We create an empty operator `\dummyop` with the same, widest limits and smash it on the `[r]`ight at the end of the second (longest) equation.

Comment: Nice approach.  I think the `\hphantom` construction should go before any of the `&`.  Replacing all `-n \leq k \leq n-1` by `\rule{100pt}{5pt}` shows that more clearly.  My understanding is that the width of the alignment will be off by half of the width of `\prod`.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with the `\mathclap` command. As I don't see what the `minipage` environment is here for, I deleted it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

  \begin{align*}
    & \prod_{\mathclap{k = -n}}^{\mathclap{n-1}}\; \biggl[\frac{k+1}{k}\biggr] = -1 \\
    & \prod_{\mathclap{j = 1}}^{n} j = \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{m^{n+1} m!}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots(n+m+1)}
  \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With this approach you've changed the horizontal spacing between the operator and its operands. Therefore, each line does not "remain identical to what (La)TeX produces by default".

Comment: Well it's shifted to the left, as you asked if I understood well. One may argue the value of the small space I add (or not)  but on the whole I find it better-looking than in your post, especially in the 2nd line, where one does not know whether the limit is equal to j or to the product of the j-s.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned why `\mathclap` doesn't cut it for me: the limits are too long.  In this simplified example, you are right that it is nicer looking to place the limits above and below `\prod`, but that cannot be done in complicated cases.  I am looking for more automatic methods, which do not require fiddling with spacing, such as with `\;` in your first line.  I picked a bad example.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a fully automatic way, since it involves aesthetic choices that may vary according to the context. I'd like to see one of your ‘complicated’ cases, just to tackle it.